# VBA Macro to find range of cells with data on Sheet1 use that range to enter formula in range on Sheet2

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

Excel 2016

Hi

I am not that proficient in VBA and I am doing my best to learn.

I have a workbook with two worksheets, `Sheet_1` and `Sheet_2`.

I am trying to write a VB macro that, if the condition `Is not blank` is met on `Sheet_1` it inserts `a formula into a specific range of cells on Sheet_2 worksheet`.

How I would like it to work is the macro finds the first and last cells with data in “Sheet 1” Column A and use that to specify the range on “Sheet 2” Column A into which to enter the  formula copied down the number of rows identified by the range from “Sheet_1”.

So if “Sheet 1” Column A has data in Cells A1 – A100 then the VB macro with enter the formula in “Sheet 2” Column A Cells A2 – A101 and the formula should auto number the numeric references in the same way that it would if it was copied down manually. "Sheet 2" has a header row hence the one row offset (A2 – A101).

I tried to post an image with an illustration of how the formula should work but the site will not allow me to but here is a link to it on postimage.

[Formula Workflow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9ooe.jpg)

This is my code for the macro so far...

```
Sub InsertFormulasTest()
    Dim Answer As VbMsgBoxResult
    Dim xRow As Long
    Dim xDirect$
    Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = Sheets("Sheet_1")
    Dim ws2 As Worksheet: Set ws2 = Sheets("Sheet_2")
    Answer = MsgBox("Insert Formula", vbYesNo, "Insert formula test")
    If Answer = vbYes Then
        Application.ScreenUpdating = False
        xRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
        If xDirect$ <> "" Then
        ws2.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.ClearContents
        xRow = 1
        ws2.Range("A2").Formula = "=IF(Sheet_1!A1>"""", ""Has Data"",""No Data"")"
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With your the last row (+1), on `ws2` you can flood-fill the formula using that last row, like this (I've just changed the last line):

```
If Answer = vbYes Then
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    xRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    If xDirect$ <> "" Then
        ws2.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.ClearContents
        xRow = 1
        ws2.Range("A2:A" & xRow).Formula = "=IF('Sheet1'!A1 > """", ""Has Data"",""No Data"")"
    End If
End If
```

Although I have no idea what xDirect$ is and what you're checking it for.

---

**try again**

```
If Answer = vbYes Then
    xRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    ws2.Range("A2:A" & xRow).ClearContents
    xRow = 1
    ws2.Range("A2:A" & xRow).Formula = "=IF('Sheet1'!A1 > """", ""Has Data"",""No Data"")"
End If
```

Comment: Hi and thanks but sadly it did not work. The yes no prompt opened and when yes is chose it seems to run but it does not clear existing data and it does not paste the formula into any cell. The `xDirect$` is from old code that I found on a web search that I have based my code upon which finds the next empty cell in a column so I used it as a starting point. Not ideal but neither are VBA skills.

Comment: I've put in a 2nd version. Get rid of the `direct$` it doesn't do anything, and the range to clear is no re-defined differently

Comment: Got it, If I replace my code with yours and then remove `Dim xDirect$` and ` If xDirect$ <> " " Then `  it works!! Thank you, very happy.

Comment: Think we both post the answer at the same time. Awesome thank you.

Comment: Having just tested it although it does work it is not counting the number of cells in Sheet1 and then adding the formula to that number of cells on Sheet 2

Comment: Having just tested it although it does work it is not `counting the number of cells in Sheet1 ` and then adding the formula to `that number of cells on `Sheet 2 ` . I have found that if I know there are 10 cells on `Sheet 1` with data and I change `xRow = 10 ` then it will insert the formula 10 times but I need the macro to automatically calculated how many times it should enter the formula as per the Formula Workflow image in the link of my post and here..
[Formula Workflow][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/v9ooe.jpg

Comment: the line `xRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1` should be returning the first empty row of column A in `ws` "Sheet_1". Is it definitely column A on sheet 1 you need to count the rows of?

Comment: Yes Column A on Sheet 1 will have the only data in that worksheet

Comment: It should work then, I don't know what is different on your code but that's a tried and tested method for the last row of a sheet I've used a hundred times.